# ошибка 404 django

Tags: python, html, django

при разработке моего первого  сайта на django,я столкнуялся с ошибкой 404 на домашней странице,причины ее возникновения мне не понятны.

содержимое index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  {% block title %}<title>Local Library</title>{% endblock %}
  <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"></meta>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></link>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  {% load static %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}"></link>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container-fluid">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      {% block sidebar %}
      <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">All books</a></li>
        <li><a href="">All authors</a></li>
      </ul>
      {% endblock %}
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-10 ">
      {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

содержимое viwes.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render


from .models import Book, Author, BookInstance, Genre

def index(request):
  
   
    num_books=Book.objects.all().count()
    num_instances=BookInstance.objects.all().count()
  
    num_instances_available=BookInstance.objects.filter(status__exact='a').count()
    num_authors=Author.objects.count()  # Метод 'all()' применён по умолчанию.

    return render(request, '//home/fedor/Project/django/fourm/templates/index.html ', context={'num_books':num_books,'num_instances':num_instances,'num_instances_available':num_instances_available,'num_authors':num_authors})
```

содержимое  site/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include
from django.urls import path
from django.views.generic import RedirectView
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.contrib import admin



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]

urlpatterns += [
     path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += [
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/catalog/', permanent=True)),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

содержимое  catalog/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

ошибка на домашней странице:

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/catualog/
Using the URLconf defined in fourm.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
catalog/
^static/(?P.*)$
The current path, catualog/, didn't match any of these.

Comment: а что у Вас в urls.py?

Comment: добавил в вопрос

Comment: вроде более менее верно, про опечатку у Вас `catalog` и `catualog` в курсе?

Comment: спасибо,не заметил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может быть ошибка в том, что у вас в site/urls.py прописан вот такой путь:

```
urlpatterns += [
     path('catalog/', include('catalog.urls')),
]
```

Соответственно, путь до главной страницы будет такой: http://127.0.0.1:8000/catalog/.

Но в ошибке у вас написан вот такой путь: http://127.0.0.1:8000/catualog/ и так как именно такого пути у вас нет, djnago и выдает 404error(страница не найдена)

Comment: спасибо,не заметил)

Comment: всегда, пожалуйста :)